# Привязка моделей

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, input, asp.net-webforms

Доброго времени суток!

Изучая фреймворк asp.net, передо мной стоит задача привязать  модели к формам, которые будут выполнять функцию фильтра среди значений с бд. Возникает несколько вопросов как это сделать в контоллере:

1. request.form, на которого я возлагал всю надежду видать работает только в случае занесения данных в бд, а не фильтрация ( ошибка: откуда-то находит `string`, когда нужен `int` и в итоге ошибка преобразования).
2. для всех значений форм лучше создавать отдельную таблицу и сверять с изначальной или все значения напрямую проверять с таблицей?

Буду крайне благодарен, если будут ссылки на источники именно по вопросу фильтрации данных ( метанит и профессорвеб уже прочитаны).

Пример: есть таблица - отображающая номера в отеле, ее модель:

```
public class Apartment
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Classes Class { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }


}

public enum Classes
{
    Econom,
    Standart,
    Luxury
}
```

Данные таблицы заполнены, моя задача - дать пользователю возможность отсортировать по его личным хотелкам ( кол-во мест в номере, его класс итд).

Часть вьюшки, реализующая хотелки:

```
<form method="post">
        <p>
            Введите количество людей:
            <input id="quan" type="number" name="quantity" method="post">

        <p>
            Выберете класс ваших аппартаментов:
            @Html.DropDownList("Class",
                            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Classes))),
                            "Выберете класс",
                            new { @class = "form-control" })
        <p>
            Дату приезда:
            <input id="date" type="date" name="startdate" method="post">

        <p>
            Дату отъезда:
            <input id="date" type="date" name="enddate" method="post">

        <p><input type="submit"></p>
    </form>
```

Собственно в контроллере у меня стоит задача реализовать логику захвата данных с этих форм и показа актуальных данных( то что хочет юзер в формах) на экран. С готовой бд из всех моих номеров, будут показываться только те, что подошли со значениями в формах.

Comment: У вас вопросы по коду, но кода в вопросе нет. То есть по сути нет вопроса. То, что вы написали просто набор слов, эти таблицы и формы существуют только у вас в голове. Приведите конкретный пример кода, который у вас вызывает затруднения.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за замечание, изменил, читайте.

Comment: Во первых, вы зачем то в html дали вашим элементам управления одинаковые id. id - это уникальный идентификатор, то есть он не должен дублироваться. Во вторых - зачем давать элементам разные значения для id и name? Сделайте их одинаковыми.

Comment: Для примера можете поглядеть [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: @tym32167 немного не понял, в каком месте у меня во вью одинаковые id. Или сам факт создания более чем одного id - не правильный?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km18h.png

Comment: @tym32167 увидел, спасибо! Сейчас просто сомневаюсь, что это поможет решить моей проблеме.

Comment: Я же скинул вам ссылку на документацию. Там пример есть на русском языке, с сортировкой и фильтрацией.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, но в документации идет работа с list, то есть мне все данные с бд сохранять в список, а потом работать непосредственно через list?

Comment: Там идет работа с контекстом БД, который берет данные из базы `var students = from s in _context.Students  select s;`